# Difference between anything but and anything other than?

Tags: idioms

If I say "anything but ordinary", it means it is not ordinary, it is unique and different.
What if "anything other than ordinary"? Does it mean the same as "anything but ordinary" or does it simplify emphasize the state of being ordinary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "nothing but", "anything but", and "everything but"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8061) and see LINKED sidebar [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34692)  [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116095)  [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89897)  [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26055)  [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9967)  [.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9323)

Comment: yes, but it didn't explain anything other than

Comment: “Anything other than ordinary” is a roundabout (and slightly clumsy) way of saying  “anything but ordinary” or “anything except ordinary”

Comment: The only context I can think of where ***but xxxx*** simply emphasises ***xxxx*** is something like *"I'm starving! I don't have time to look at the menu! Just give me **anything - but quick!**"*. So I think this question is General Reference, not a duplicate of *nothing/anything/everything but xxxx*.